# Social media checks?

Tags: professionalism

When employers want to check your social media presence, what do they check?

Facebook, Insta, twitter etc?

Is it checked out using your name, email address or phone number?

And does it tend to be an initial, preliminary check, or something that is continuously monitored?

Comment: Hmmm,.... not so much, more worried about what they know about me. eg my youtube viewing (materialistic, fickle) etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are professional checkers that check EVERYTHING.

Expect any public statement you've made anywhere to be fair game.  That includes youtube videos, anything still on myspace, linkedin, instagram, check by phone number, photo lookup, friends pages, et cetera.

It varies, but consider it constantly monitored

Comment: True up to a point ;-)  but Hardcastle PLC is not going to have the resources of the CIA - and some of what you suggest would leave companies open to age, sex, orientation and ethnicity and religion law suits

Comment: @Neuromancer sure, if they could prove it.